# Web Audio audiocontext createMediaStreamSource stuttering

Tags: javascript, stream, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I want to mix different audio media streams in to one stream. I'm been doing this with Web Audio audiocontext and createMediaStreamSource.

**But the final mixed audio is stuttering.**

Have anyone an idea how to optimize this to avoid stuttering?

```
// init audio context
var audioContext = new AudioContext({ latencyHint: 0 });
var audioDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

// add audio streams
audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream1).connect(audioDestination);
audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream2).connect(audioDestination);
audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream3).connect(audioDestination);
audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream4).connect(audioDestination);

// get mixed audio stream tracks
var audioTrack = audioDestination.stream.getTracks()[0];

// get video track
var videoTrack = videoStream.getTracks()[0];

// combine video and audio tracks into single stream.
var finalStream = new MediaStream([videoTrack, audioTrack]);

// assign to video element
el_video.srcObject = finalStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `latencyHint` to `'playback'` like this:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext({ latencyHint: 'playback' });
```

This allows the browser to add a bit of latency to the audio graph which can help on underpowered devices. Setting the `latencyHint` to `0` on the other hand will tell the browser that it should do things as fast as possible which increases the risk of dropouts.

Having said that, the `latencyHint` is only a hint. The browser may very well ignore it. You can check what the browser is actually doing by inspecting the `baseLatency` property.

```
console.log(audioContext.baseLatency);
```

Comment: On iPhone 7 with IOS 14 this does not work unfortunately, because audioContext.baseLatency is undefined and not supported appearantly.

Comment: Unfortunately Safari's Web Audio implementation is way behind the spec right now. But there is at least some progress. https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/265393/webkit/

Comment: update: supposedly with Safari 14.7, this is supported - see link from chrisguttandin

Comment: Still not supported on latest iOS 15 (it only supports READING the current latency, but not giving a hint. Setting latencyHint to 'playback' when starting the AudioContext still gives a baseLatency of 0.003 s (and stuttering if you do anything meaningful with the audio graph))